# How to replace value NA in R on specific text match

Tags: r, dplyr

sample_df<-

```
Product Code      Remark
12200234          Done
12200234          Done
12200205          Error
12200256          Error,Pending
12200126          Error,Hold
```

How I can replace those value which contains text as Error in Remarks column to NA.

OP

```
Product Code      Remark
12200234          Done
12200234          Done
12200205          NA
12200256          NA
12200126          NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
sample_df %>% 
    mutate(Remark= case_when(str_detect(Remark, "Error") ~ NA_character_,
                       TRUE ~ Remark))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `grepl`. It checks for Error string in `Remark` and replaces with NA

```
library(dplyr)

sample_df %>% 
  mutate(Remark= case_when(grepl("Error", Remark) ~ "NA",
                           TRUE ~ Remark))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  `Product Code` Remark
           <dbl> <chr> 
1       12200234 Done  
2       12200234 Done  
3       12200205 NA    
4       12200256 NA    
5       12200126 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require(gData)

myDf$Remark[startsWith(myDf$Remark, "Error")] <- NA
```

If you don't want the tidyverse solution given above. As well as grepl, there is also a tidyverse starts_with function...